# Calling custom phtml file in widget

Tags: widget

I currently call a custom phtml file in CMS pages to display a single product with description, price etc.

```
 {{block type="catalog/product" product_id="7160" template="catalog/product/dynamic-product-image_howto.phtml"}}
```

I'm trying to include this in a custom widget - is it possible to call in phtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is what you need, but give it a try.
In the phtml for your widget do this:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product')->setProductId(7160)
       ->setTemplate('catalog/product/dynamic-product-image_howto.phtml');

echo $block->toHtml();
```

Comment: @Marius : How I can call a widget in .phtml file. I have a widget which is pre configured by the theme and I need to show it on my custom .phtml template. How I can do this. I have tried this [Link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107750/magento-2-call-a-widget-in-phtml-file) but not working