# Magento 2: Call a Widget in a .phtml file

Tags: magento2, widget

I have a widget:

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="all_products" products_count="5" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

So it works in the content of the CMS block or CMS page. I want to show it in a .phtml file, how can I do it?

Comment: Why you prefer add widget in phtml rather than in layout xml?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For Display Type = All Product Widget**

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" 
display_type="all_products" products_count="5" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("all_products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

**For Display Type = New Product Widget**

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="new_products" products_count="5" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("new_products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: This not working in Magento 2.1.1

Comment: check update its works fine

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the customer module, for example:

**vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml**

```
<?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
<?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
    <?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

As we can see, we can call a widget directly in the phtml template: **$block->getLayout()->createBlock('your\widget')**.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code and check if it works:

```
<?php
    $filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
    $_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="2"}}');
    echo $_widget; 
?>
```

**Where page_id="2" is my widget is just replaced with your widget id .**

Comment: Opps that is magento 1 seem like this link: http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.com/2014/03/call-widget-in-phtml-file-magento.html

Comment: This is the correct way explained here [Correct way to add widget in .phtml file](http://www.bloggingtipsntricks.com/call-widget-in-phtml-file-in-magento/)

Comment: @muditmehrotra No, that's for Magento 1.