# how to show stock quantity on module-catalog-widget (luma theme, grid.phtml)

Tags: magento2

I try to show product quantity on module-catalog-widget (grid.phtml) by using the below code (Magento 2.3)

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
$qty = $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId());
echo  $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId());

?>
```

It showed that We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.

Please anyone help me, which code should be used on product widget front page luma magento2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to grid.phtml file call on widget  ??? If yes check link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/116263/85907

Comment: I need to add code in grid.phtml to show stock qty on front page. I try many code but it not showed. Thank you.

Comment: try this code `<?php  $ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
    echo $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>`

Comment: It still showed "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.", please advise.

Comment: that code can be used on product catalog but on front page is not shown. Today I try a lot of code but not successful.

Comment: you means above code use in other file but not working grid.phtml file ???